# Extended ASCII charatcer string convert into Hex format

Tags: format, char, hex, ascii

I am trying to convert the input ascii string to hex format using the format specifier "%.2X" . I have pasted the program at below which does the same. But, this program works in Linux server its giving improper hex output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char *buffer = "<9e>¥/gÿbbbbABCD";
char *newBuffer = new char[strlen(buffer)*2 + 1];
for(int i = 0; i< strlen(buffer); ++i)
{
    sprintf(newBuffer+(2*i), "%02x", buffer[i]); 
     //cout<<"\t"<<newBuffer;
}
  cout<<"\t"<<newBuffer;
  return 0;
}
```

o/p: 3c39653effff2f67ffff6262626241424344
for this extended ASCII char ¥ and ÿ is giving ffff and ffff.

Please tell me how to convert properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we typecast the source string with `unsigned char`, the problem gets solved:

```
sprintf(newBuffer+(2*i), "%02x", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
```